# Is optane memory not compatible with my build

Tags: windows-10

I built a desktop with the following parts:

- 32gb Intel optane memory
- 500 gb western digital nvme m.2 ssd
- windows 10 home
- i7-8700k
- evga 1080ti
- seagate SATA 2tb HDD
- asus rog strix z370e- gaming motherboard

My problem: I setup and turned on my computer. Installed windows 10. Went into bios and turned on the optane acceleration option. I was not sure if it was working at that point and checked online for drivers. When I went to install intel’s optane software it told me I had to uninstall the Intel rapid software before installing so I did. On computer restart I got a blue screen. This continued until I turned off the optane setting in bios. I am not sure how to undo what I did, and also get my optane memory to work with my 2tb hdd as expected. Are my components all compatible? When I turn off the optane setting in bios, it starts up correctly.

Attempted fixes:
- I tried to reinstall the Intel rapid storage technology software 
- I deleted everything on the SSD, formatted, and reinstalled windows

Is it safe / should I reformat the optane memory?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  You do indeed to install the drivers in order for optane to work

Comment: @Ramhound , sorry I tried to fill in extra details as I do not entirely understand what my problem is other than "When I turn on the bios acceleration, I get a bluescreen". I installed optane drivers through ai suite 3 and it still did not work. do you have recommendations as to what noise I should leave out?

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your installation method,
since Intel Rapid Storage Technology is actually a pre-requisite for
the Intel Optane M.2 NVMe Accelerator.

You might try to get your drivers not via AI Suite 3 but by direct download from Intel at
[Intel® Optane™ Memory User Interface and Driver for System Acceleration](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28072/Intel-Optane-Memory-User-Interface-and-Driver-for-System-Acceleration?v=t).
Check that your hardware is listed in the article.

Get also the
[Intel® Optane™ Memory Installation and User Guide (PDF)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/memory-and-storage/optane-memory/intel-optane-memory-user-installation.pdf),
and check that you are doing it right.

In case of difficulties, the procedure in this [Dell article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln306433/how-to-install-an-intel-optane-m2-nvme-accelerator-into-your-existing-dell-optiplex-inspiron-precision-alienware-system?lang=en)
might be helpful, with much detail and screenshots.

Please note that you need a small 5MB partition *at the end of your primary drive* for the Optane utility to use.

Comment: I will try following these steps when I get home later and reply more accurately. My general worry was that optane/drivers were setup correctly to start, but I uninstalled something I was not supposed to and now can't get it back into a stable state. i am willing to reformat everything on my computer, is that safe (HDD, m2 SSD, and optane)? Will this get me to a clean slate?

Comment: It will get you to a clean state, but you should take great precautions before formatting, such as taking a system disk image, creating a boot CD/USB to restore and testing it, and ensure that you have all required drivers and installation media for your applications. For disk image I recommend AOMEI Backupper Freeware.

Comment: I already formatted it (SSD) once, did I possibly ruin my windows installation? I had nothing but windows on it, as I literally just built the computer with brand new parts. I have disks for the motherboard drivers/software as well as the GPU.